# Oracle SQL Return Single Row Based On Max Value of a Column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have in my database table

> a | 1
>
> a | 2
>
> a | 3
>
> a | 4

How should I return only with a SELECT query:

> a | 4

I have tried several combination with distinct and max values but all seem to be irrelevant.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Is `a` constant, or do you expect other values there, too? Otherwise, you can just do `select 'a', max(b) from table`. Also, if there are other values, do you want to see them, or just the one with the max value?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT MAX(a) AS a FROM <TABLE>
```

Edit: I thought "a" was the name of the column, if it is another column, use

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY col1
```

which will return one row per col1 value. If there are other values there (like b, c), it depends on what you want.

Comment: This will only return one row??

Comment: this will return all rows.

Answer (score 6):

the query is this:

```
select * from yourTable 
where B = (select max(B) from yourTable);
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you dont just want to get a|4 but there are other similar combinations like b|3, c|6 etc,
So assuming the columns are c1, c2, the query would be

```
select * from table_1 where (c2) in (select max(c2) from table_1 group by c1)
```

If your table is like

```
C1|C2
a|1
a|2
a|4
b|3
c|2
c|6
```

the output would be like

```
a|4
b|3
c|6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use analytic functions for this (assuming the name column contains the 'a' and the value column contains 1,2,3,4, ...):

```
select * from (
  select name, value, rownum over (partition by 1 order by value desc) 
  as rn
  from mytable)
where rn = 1
```

Or, you can use a plain old ORDER BY:

```
select * from (
  select name, value
  from mytable
  order by value desc)
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table T has two columns C1 and C2, have you tried it following way?

```
select C1, C2 from T where C2 in (select max(C2) from T)
```

EDIT - I tried mine as well as other suggested answers, and to my surprise, this one is working best for me, even though I have to do full table scan in the sub-query. If you've got what you were looking for, could you please share it with us, or mark the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
select Col_A,Col_B
from Table_X
where Col_B =(select max(Col_B) from Table_X)
```

Answer (score -3):

If the a you have given are values in the table then you can use

```
select column_name, max(column_b) from table_name
```